# No ouput from lexer in lex and yacc

Tags: c++, token, flex-lexer, lex

I am observing a weird behavior while using lex and yacc.

Here is my lex file -- **ex.l**

```
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

#include "y.tab.h" 
 
void yyerror(char *);  // to get the token types that we return
%}

%%
[ \t] ;

[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ { yylval.fval = atof(yytext); //this is not working 
                 cout << "lex found an float: "; return FLOATS; }
[0-9]+  { cout << "lex found an int: "; yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return INTS; }
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ {
     
    char *res = new char[strlen(yytext) + 1];
    strcpy(res, yytext);
    yylval.sval = res;
    return STRINGS;
}

. ;

%%
```

hHre is my yacc file -- **ex.y**

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ; 

extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();
extern FILE *yyin;
extern int yynerrs; 
extern void yyerror(char *s);
%}

%union {
    int ival;
    float fval;
    char *sval;
}

%token <ival> INTS
%token <fval> FLOATS
%token <sval> STRINGS

%%

grammar:
    INTS grammar { cout << "yacc found an int: " << $1 << endl; }
    | FLOATS grammar { cout << "yacc found a float: " << $1 << endl; }
    | STRINGS grammar { cout << "yacc found a string: " << $1 << endl; }
    | INTS { cout << "yacc found an int: " << $1 << endl; }
    | FLOATS { cout << "yacc found a float: " << $1 << endl; }
    | STRINGS { cout << "yacc found a string: " << $1 << endl; }
    ;
%%
#include <stdio.h>

 
main() {
     yyin = stdin;
    do {
    yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
    
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
    cout << "EEK, parse error!  Message: " << s << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```

After compiling these two and running them, I don't get the output from the lex for ex:-

[image: output]

Why is it happening? Why isn't cout statement in action of lex working?

Comment: You did not enter any float number, as far as I can see. ;)

Comment: Your cout statements in ex.l don't have any values after them - if you put `cout << "lex found an float: " << yylval.fval` then it will work.

Comment: @codebeard : why so ??? now its working ??

Comment: I'm not 100% clear about what output you expect to see... With your original code I got: `./a.out / 
34 /
lex found an int: /
56 /
lex found an int: /
78 /
lex found an int: /
yacc found an int: 78 /
yacc found an int: 56 /
yacc found an int: 34`

Comment: now it's working . but why it was not working when yyval.faval is not present ??Any idea

Comment: It was working for me before I made that change.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is I think the following code in ex.y.

```
%token <ival> INTS
%token <fval> FLOATS
%token <sval> STRINGS
```

There the inbuilt tokens are used. That overrides the tokens defined in ex.l file. In a sense, the execution never reaches the cout lines in ex.l file.

Try writing only following code & it should work.

```
%token INTS
%token FLOATS
%token STRINGS
```

Hope this helps.

NOTE: I have not tested the code. So you may get other errors after doing this.